# detailTextLabel not showing until selecting a row

Tags: ios, iphone

hey guys I have a problem with a uitableviewcell, the problem is by the detailTextLabel, which I have set to right detail in the storyboard. When the view appears everything except the strings of the detailTextLabel shows up. So now to the real strange part, when I select a row suddenly the text appears.

So here's my code for the cellAtIndexPathRow: method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section ==2) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"lastCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:
                _datePicker = [UIDatePicker new];
                _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
                [cell addSubview:_datePicker];
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Delete alarm", nil);
                break;
        }
        return cell;
    } else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
        //cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Repeat", nil);
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Mo. Tu. We.";
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Cycles", nil);
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"7";
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Description", nil);
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Alarm";
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Sound", nil);
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Radar";
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
                break;
            case 4:
                _snoozeSwitch = [UISwitch new];
                [_snoozeSwitch setOn:YES];
                [_snoozeSwitch addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(updateSwitch:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                cell.accessoryView = _snoozeSwitch;
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Snooze", nil);
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"%s:BUG!",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

So I hope for ur help thanks guys

Answer (score 5):

Did you get this problem with iOS 8 after change the `detailTextLabel` to an empty string like:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
```

Then at a later point change the text to a different non-empty string, the string does not appear. 
If you print `detailTextLabel` frame you can see `detailTextLabel` size: `{0,0}` 
Try `[cell setNeedsLayout];` after setting the text.
It works in this case.
[Helpful link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2628089?start=0&tstart=0)

**#Edit** 
I did test in iOS 8.1 `[cell setNeedsLayout];` didn't work.
Try `[cell layoutIfNeeded];` instead

Comment: I see this behavior on iOS 7 too.. 
`[cell setNeedsLayout]` helps on iOS 7, but on iOS 8 things become even more strange: `textLabel` (main text label) shifts upper during layout, but `detailTextLabel` still does not appear. And cell selection reveals the detail text, as before.

Comment: well, did you try `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or try create cell in this case.

Comment: I use static cells and it is not appropriate for in my case because it will clear custom-assigned detailTextLabels on other cells, as well as current one.
Figured out that iOS 8 removes detailTextLabel from cell subviews if it is empty. Calling `[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.detailTextLabel]` before `[cell setNeedsLayout]` did the trick for me:)

Comment: "Figured out that iOS 8 removes `detailTextLabel` from cell subviews if it is empty". I dont think so, I did check with iOS 8.0 and 8.1 `detailTextLabel` is not removed actualy, its size is `CGSizeZero`. and `[cell setNeedsLayout]` actualy not work I'm so sorry. I will edit my answer and you not need re-add `detailTextLabel` It not need

Comment: @Cemen see my edit  bro :) you need use [cell layoutIfNeeded]; only without re-add detailTextLabel

Comment: tried that too:) main label goes upper, but detail still not appear.. For static cell only `addSubview` helped in my app:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the best solution I could figure out was to set the text to @" " instead of @"".
[cell setNeedsLayout]
[cell layoutIfNeeded]
and/or
[reloadRowsAtIndexPaths..]
all didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

We can't look at the code responsible for this behavior, but we can try and understand their intentions. I bet they don't initialize the label because they don't want to use resources for an empty UILabel. After all the detailTextLabel is an optional, so it might not exist.

When you create the cell apple automatically sets detailTextLabel.text to "Subtitle" (in interface builder). So instead of changing the text to "" set the default “Subtitle" to hidden.

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.hidden = true
```

Since we don't know exactly what is happening when there is an empty label its best not set it to "". Especially if cells are being reused.